# Conversion of Visual Basic Code to C# - code with strange types handling

Tags: c#, vb.net, basic

I am a newbie in Visual Basic, I only need to convert a piece of code from Visual Basic to C# :).

I have some Visual basic code:

object

```
    Structure Row
        Dim mValue() As Object
    End Structure
```

a function with weakly typed code:

```
Protected Function ReadData(typeCode As Int32) As Object
        Select Case typeCode
            Case DataType.TYPE_BOOL
                Return GetUByte()
            Case DataType.TYPE_UINT8
                Return GetUByte()
            Case DataType.TYPE_CHAR8
                Return GetChar()
            Case DataType.TYPE_INT8
                Return GetSByte()
            Case DataType.TYPE_INT16
                Return GetInt16()
            Case DataType.TYPE_UINT16
                Return GetUInt16()
            Case DataType.TYPE_INT32
                Return GetInt32()
            Case DataType.TYPE_UINT32
                Return GetUInt32()
            Case DataType.TYPE_INT64
                Return GetInt64()
            Case DataType.TYPE_UINT64
                Return GetUInt64()
            Case DataType.TYPE_FLOAT
                Return GetFloat()
            Case DataType.TYPE_STRING8
                Return GetString8()
            Case DataType.TYPE_HASHEDSTRING8
                Return GetHashedString8()
            Case DataType.TYPE_OBJECT
                Return GetObject()
            Case DataType.TYPE_VECTOR
                Return GetVector()
            Case DataType.TYPE_FLOAT2
                Return GetVector2()
            Case DataType.TYPE_FLOAT3
                Return GetVector3()
            Case DataType.TYPE_FLOAT4
                Return GetVector4()
            Case DataType.TYPE_TABLESETREFERENCE
                Return GetTableSetRef()
            Case DataType.TYPE_RESOURCEKEY
                Return GetResourceKey()
            Case DataType.TYPE_LOCKEY
                Return GetLocKey()
            Case DataType.TYPE_UNDEFINED
                MsgBox("Unknown type code " & typeCode)
            Case Else
                Throw New Exception("Invalid data type in binary table: " & typeCode)
        End Select
```

as you can see, this function returns a value, that could be one of many types.

And code of assigning value of the array:

```
Dim r As Row
r.mValue(0) = ReadData(someArg)
```

After some code there is strange code:

```
Dim a = r.mValue(0).mDataOffset;
```

Where mDataOffset is attribute of one class of classes, that could be returned by ReadData! I think, it is possible from `GetTableSetRef`, that has type

```
public struct StringRef
    {
        public UInt32 mDataOffset;
        public long startofDataOffset;
    }
```

I think, Visual Basic is weakly typed language, but how to convert such code?

I've tried something like

```
UInt32 child_pos = r.mValue[0].mDataOffset;
```

but `r.mValue[0]` is `Object`, that has not `.mDataOffset`...

Thank you very much!

Comment: what happens if you try to cast it to `StringRef` first?

Comment: VB can be strong or weak typed, depending on if you have set `Option Strict On` or `Option Strict Off`

Comment: What is the value of `someArg`? That seems to indicate the return type of the `ReadData` method.

Comment: The tag _VBA_ is probably not correct. Is your code _VB.NET_?

Comment: Hello! Thank you! Changed to vb.net.

Comment: someArg is always ReadData(typeCode As Int32)

Comment: To @RufusL: The main problem, that I didn't know, what type should be returned type in each case of ReadData call. That's main problem - I tought about casting, but I still can't understand, what types should be in each call of the function :)